# Getting info from next line in for loop

Tags: python-2.7, for-loop, if-statement, coordinates

I am using a for loop to read a file of coordinates line by line. In some cases I need the information from the next line in order do math at the current line, such as the distance formula.

The file contents look like  this:

```
X66.745 Y108.729 
X67.255 Y108.584 
X139.519 Y90.769
X142.494 Y90.161
X143.062 Y90.068
```

It has other content in it, however this is the what the useful content looks like.

My current code is:

```
def get_xy_coord(line):
    x_coord = []
    y_coord = []
    line_list = line.split()
    x_ = line_list[1].split('X')
    x_ = x_[1]
    x_coord.append(x_)
    y_ = line_list[2].split('Y')
    y_ = y_[1]
    y_coord.append(y_)
    return x_coord[-1:], y_coord[-1:]




### Load File

file_name = 'path'  # put your filename here

with open(file_name, 'r+') as f:
    contents = f.readlines()

    for line in contents:
        if 'X' in line:
            x1, y1 get_xy_coord(line)
            #get x2 , y2 to do distance formula
```

I have read other post on getting the next line, but none of them have worked for my application, such as the next() option, which I think is because I am working with a file rather than a list of values. After using the content of line and the line after it, I would still like to just advance 1 line as if it where a normal for loop iteration.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of a generator function, that returns you always 2 lines from the file:

```
def line2Points(l):
    return {p[0].lower(): float(p[1:]) for p in l.strip().split(' ')}

def pairs(f):
    # Generator function to read 2 lines
    i = iter(f)
    prev = i.next()
    for item in i:
        yield prev, item
        prev = item

with open(file_name, 'r+') as f:
    coords = pairs(f)
    for currentLine, nextLine in coords:
        currentPoint = line2Points(currentLine)
        nextPoint = line2Points(nextLine)
        print currentPoint, '>>>', nextPoint
```

This will print the current and next coordinate together:

```
{'y': 108.729, 'x': 66.745} >>> {'y': 108.584, 'x': 67.255}
{'y': 108.584, 'x': 67.255} >>> {'y': 90.769, 'x': 139.519}
{'y': 90.769, 'x': 139.519} >>> {'y': 90.161, 'x': 142.494}
{'y': 90.161, 'x': 142.494} >>> {'y': 90.068, 'x': 143.062}
```

Comment: This could work for me. How would this handle special cases such as needing to jump n lines ahead or if the next line had different formatting? The entire file does not follow the format shown.

Comment: You could skip irrelevant lines in the for loop: `for currentLine, nextLine in coords:for currentLine, nextLine in coord`. For example `if not currentLine.startswith('X'): continue` ...